# A meta thread for interesting but not sufficiently answered questions on CS?

Tags: discussion, other-se-sites

MO has [a meta thread](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1967/interesting-and-not-sufficiently-answered-questions-on-math-se) for listing questions on Math.SE which are interesting but have not been sufficiently answered on Math.SE.

Should we have something similar for interesting not-sufficiently answered questions on CS.SE?

Comment: Given the votes, it sounds like the answer is "Yes".  Want to create one?  (Let's not use this thread for that, but create a new thread with the guidelines on what to post and how to vote etc., as MO did.)

Comment: think there are many such excellent questions but one problem is "interesting" is purely subjective. suggest people just start blogs with their lists of favorite not-fully-answered questions & compare notes. chat is another place for such discussions. (and why is this one so dead? ... strong contrast with eg physics site which is quite active!) :(